# RDF data - can not saved to file in disk

Tags: rdf, owl, fileoutputstream

I have read an owl file(Student.owl) using Jena. I am using two models: model1 contains the data read from Student.owl . I will then create a class or two and its individuals using Jena, keep it in model2 and will store it in the file Student.owl.

How can I save my new class and its individuals to the Rdf file Student.owl. I have tried this code but it does not work and even damages/lose data from my owl file.

```
try {
    String file="C://Student.owl";
    FileOutputStream f1=new FileOutputStream(file, true);

    model.write(f1,"RDF/XML");
} catch(Exception e) {}
```

Comment: "it does not work" is not a problem description. What exactly goes wrong? Do you get any errors or warnings?

Comment: that is what I mentioned that it destroys all my existing data in the Student.owl.

Comment: Actually, you didn't mention anything about "existing data" in the file, until now.

Comment: As Jeen explained in the answer below, you have to work on the existing ontology, i.e. load it into a model and modify that model - then you can simply write back to the same file - default is overwrite.

Comment: Could you solve the issue? If yes, please provide an answer and accept it. That's how Stackoverflow is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

`model.write` cannot just append to an existing file.

In order to add to your existing file, you need to first *read* the file into your model, then add the additional data to your model, and then finally write the model back to it.

Comment: it means my model2 (where my additional data contains) will first read the file, then I will add the required class/individuals to it.. I do not understand "delete/clear the file". That file contains model1, it means huge data so how can I delete it. I know its my lack of understanding, you mean something else?

Comment: There is no need for clearing the file as Jena default is simply to overwrite the file.

Comment: So then what is wrong with my approach? The only thing I did not do is I have not read the file with model2. I read it with model1, have added a class, write that class in model2 and simply tried to write the model2 to the file.

Comment: @Neha we don't know what's wrong with your approach because you haven't shown us the relevant code, and your explanation is confusing. Try editing your question, add a [mcve] that clearly demonstrates what exactly the problem is.